# Reading 3 strings from keyboard in C but only get two strings when I print them?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

The problem I have is the following: I want to read from keyboard 3 strings(s1,s2,s3).What is the best way to do this without any problem and then I want to print those 3 strings.I give the 3 strings but in the print section I only get s2 and s3,but s1 is blank!

Here's my code guys!:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define M 4

int main(){

char buffer[255];
char s1[M],s2[M],s3[M+1];

printf("Give first string: ");
scanf("%s",buffer);

while(strlen(buffer) > 4){
    printf("lenght of string must be <= 4\n");
    printf("Give first String again : ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
}
strncpy(s1,buffer,5);

printf("Give second string: ");
scanf("%s",buffer);


while(strlen(buffer) > 4){
    printf("lenght of string must be <= 4\n");
    printf("Give second String again : ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
}

strncpy(s2,buffer,5);


printf("Give third string: ");
scanf("%s",buffer);


while(strlen(buffer) > 5){
    printf("lenght of string must be <= 5\n");
    printf("Give third String again : ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
}
strncpy(s3,buffer,5);


printf("First String : %s\n",s1);
printf("Second String : %s\n",s2);
printf("Third String : %s\n",s3);

return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you try to copy 5 characters into the array of maximal 4: strncpy(s1,buffer,5); ?

Comment: Notice that standard C does not know about the keyboard. You should test the returned item count from `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy()` doesn't null terminate the strings and you need to take care of it else your code will lead to undefined behavior.

Also

```
M=4
```

and you are copying 5 character which will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your strings are not terminated.  You need to allow for an extra space in each buffer for a '\0' character at the end of the string.  Make all your buffers bigger by 1 and ether set the to 0 to start with

```
memset(&buf1, 0, sizeof(buf1));
```

or explicitly set the last index of that buffer to '\0'

Answer (score 0):

```
#define M 4
...
char s1[M],s2[M],s3[M+1];
...
strncpy(s1,buffer,5)
```

In the code above (extracted from your program) you copy `5` bytes (or less) in a buffer of size `4`. When `buffer` contains a string of size `4` (`strlen(buffer) == 4`), `strncpy(s1, buffer, 5)` copies `5` characters to `s1` and the fifth character is the `NUL` character (the string terminator).

Because `s1` has room for only `4` characters, the terminator is written in a memory that does not belong to `s1` but to a different variable.

It's recommended to use [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) and not [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) when you deal with user input to avoid buffer overflows. However, what you accomplished here is exactly a buffer overflow.

The solution is simple and it involves two easy steps:

- declare `s1` and `s2` as `char [5]` too;
- use `M` everywhere, avoid the hardcoded constants in the code; using constants (`#define`s) allows easier change of the value, if needed:

  ```
  ...

  char s1[M+1],s2[M+1],s3[M+1];

  printf("Give first string: ");
  scanf("%s",buffer);

  while(strlen(buffer) > M){
      printf("length of string must be <= %d\n", M);
      printf("Give first String again : ");
      scanf("%s",buffer);
  }
  strncpy(s1,buffer,M+1);

  ...
  (repeat the changes above to `s2` and `s3`)
  ```

Answer (score -1):

In your code,

```
 strncpy(s1,buffer,5);
```

creates memory overrun , as `s1` is having only `4` bytes allocated. This, in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Same for

```
 strncpy(s2,buffer,5);
```

Solution:

- Either use `#define M 5`
- or, keep `#define M 4`, and  define your arrays like

  ```
   char s1[M+1],s2[M+1],s3[M+1];
  ```

so that, there is enough space to store the terminating null. (`\0`)

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the reason behind the downvote so that I can corrct myself? Thank you. :-)